# No mapping found with @RestController an @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have the following Controller

```
@RestController("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
                    )
    public List<PersonNode> getPersons(){

        return personService.getList();

    }

}
```

Now the spring neo4j config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="server.infrastructure.repositories.neo4j.config" />

</beans>
```

and spring mvc rest config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--Used for Spring MVC configuration - must have-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- This shows where to scan for rest controller -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="server.api.rest.controller" />

</beans>
```

and `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <display-name>Restful Web Application with Spring MVC 4.0.5x</display-name>

    <!-- Root App Context -->
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Context Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context.Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Web App Settings -->
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>MR.rest.api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringMVC/SpringMVC-RESTContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MR.rest.api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However when I refer to `http://localhost:8080/rest/person/list` i keep getting the:

> [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/person/list] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MR.rest.api'

with my Tomcat startup log:

```
...
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01:50:55.703 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
01:50:55.774 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 16 01:50:55 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
01:50:55.805 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/ApplicationContext.xml]
01:50:55.879 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/Neo4j-DataSources.xml]
01:50:56.254 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'myNeo4jConfiguration' of type [class server.infrastructure.repositories.neo4j.config.MyNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7212f882] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
01:50:56.257 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
01:50:56.683 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Starting Post-processing phase
01:50:56.684 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building annotation class map
01:50:56.684 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building interface class map for 6 classes
01:50:56.684 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Registering default type converters...
01:50:56.692 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Post-processing complete
01:50:56.692 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - 6 classes loaded in 22 milliseconds
01:50:56.974 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext - Neo4jMappingContext initialisation completed
01:50:57.088 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslator
01:50:57.092 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
01:50:57.095 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising Neo4jTransactionManager
01:50:57.130 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1424 ms
01:50:57.161 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api': initialization started
gru 16, 2015 1:50:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api'
01:50:57.165 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 16 01:50:57 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
01:50:57.166 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringMVC/SpringMVC-RESTContext.xml]
01:50:57.399 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.util.List<server.infrastructure.persistence.neo4j.nodes.PersonNode> server.api.rest.controller.PersonController.getPersons()
01:50:57.626 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 16 01:50:57 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
01:50:57.694 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 16 01:50:57 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
01:50:57.758 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/person] onto handler '/person'
01:50:57.826 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api': initialization completed in 665 ms
gru 16, 2015 1:50:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

However, when I refer to `http://localhost:8080/rest/list` I get the expected list of persons.

I want to refer to the `http://localhost:8080/rest/person/list` while using the `@RestController` for the person at class level and the `list' at the method level. How this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add @RequestMapping to your Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

   @Autowired
   PersonService personService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public List<PersonNode> getPersons(){
     return personService.getList();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but why the `@RestController("/person")` does not work?

Comment: The value indicated in the RestController annotation is a suggestion for a logical component name like others annotation Service, Repository and is not used as url mapping to your controller.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So this logical component name is never used or can it be used somehow?

Comment: I am sorry for this late response, but i got your confussion.
That name has been used as a bean name so that the application context could look up.
If you leave it blank, a default name will be used.
I think it is better to use *name* attribute instead of *value* one.